# gnuplot rowstacked histogram: how to put sum above bars

Tags: label, gnuplot, histogram

This question is related to [gnuplot histogram: How to put values on top of bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460937/gnuplot-histogram-how-to-put-values-on-top-of-bars).

I have a datafile `file.dat`:

```
x y1 y2
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
```

and the gnuplot:

```
set style data histogram;
set style histogram rowstacked;
plot newhistogram 'foo', 'file.dat' u 2:xtic(1) t col, '' u 3 t col;
```

Now I want to place the *sums* of columns 2 and 3 above the bars. The obvious solution

```
plot newhistogram 'foo', 'file.dat' u 2:xtic(1) t col, '' u 3 t col, \
'' u ($0-1):($2+$3+0.2):($2+$3) notitle w labels font "Arial,8";
```

puts the labels in the correct place, but the calculated sum is wrong. That is, in `($0-1):($2+$3+0.2):($2+$3)`, the second `$2` appears to evaluate to zero.

What's going wrong here and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must give an explicit string as label:

```
 plot newhistogram 'foo', 'file.dat' u 2:xtic(1) t col, '' u 3 t col, \
'' u ($0-1):($2+$3):(sprintf('%.1f', $2+$3)) notitle w labels offset 0,1 font "Arial,8"
```

As other improvement, I would use the `offset` option which allows you to give an displacement in character units, which doesn't depend on the yrange.

(Side note: if a value from a column is used, then one can skip the explicit formatting of the label, like `using 1:2:2 with labels`, but in general one should use `sprintf` to format the label)

Comment: Note that in the case of a datafile with both positive and negative sums, the correct offset is no longer constant, so unfortunately you cannot use `offset` (which expects a fixed displacement) but must use the yrange-dependent method.

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is a very, very ugly hack: insert some new lines when the value is negative: `sprintf("%s%.1f", ($2+$3) < 0 ? "\n\n" : "", $2+$3)`. Disclaimer: don't try this at home ;)