# gnuplot: How to put sum above bars with clustered stacked histograms

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

Thanks to the question [gnuplot rowstacked histogram: how to put sum above bars](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30872665/8031185) and its answer, I learned how to add the sum of stacked histograms above their bars. However, I can't figure out how to achieve this with stacked histograms that are clustered. As shown in the below code, I can get the sum which seem to be placed at the right y coordinates.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to change the x coordinates for the second and third clusters, so they end up overlapping the first cluster's sum labels. What do I need to do to  change the x coordinates of the sums so that they appear over the correct bars?

```
set term png size 1200, 500
set output "graph.png"
set datafile separator ","

set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid
set style data histograms
set style histogram rowstack

set offset -1.3,-0.3,100,0
set yrange [*:*] noextend
set xrange [*:*] noextend

set key outside
set key right top
set ylabel "Time (ms)"
set xtics font ", 10"

plot newhistogram at 0, "a.csv" u 2:xtic(1) t "Download" lc 1, \
    '' u 3:xtic(1) t "Transfer" lc 2, \
    '' u 4:xtic(1) t "Return" lc 3, \
    '' u 5:xtic(1) t "Processing" lc 4, \
    '' u 6:xtic(1) t "Wait" lc 5, \
    '' u 7:xtic(1) t "Overhead" lc 6, \
    '' u 0:($2+$3+$4+$5+$6+$7):(sprintf('%d', $2+$3+$4+$5+$6+$7)) not with labels offset 0,0.7, \
  newhistogram at 3, "b.csv" u 2:xtic(1) t "" lc 1,\
    for [i=3:7] '' u i:xtic(1) t "" lc (i - 1), \
    '' u 0:($2+$3+$4+$5+$6+$7):(sprintf('%d', $2+$3+$4+$5+$6+$7)) not with labels offset 0,0.7, \
  newhistogram at 6, "c.csv" u 2:xtic(1) t "" lc 1,\
    for [i=3:7] '' u i:xtic(1) t "" lc (i - 1), \
    '' u 0:($2+$3+$4+$5+$6+$7):(sprintf('%d', $2+$3+$4+$5+$6+$7)) not with labels offset 0,0.7
```

Data files:

- a.csv

  ```
  Device,Download,Transfer,Return,Processing,Wait,Overhead
  Find X2 Pro,350,0,0,287,1,24
  OnePlus 8,350,29,19,410,30,138
  ```
- b.csv

  ```
  Device,Download,Transfer,Return,Processing,Wait,Overhead
  Find X2 Pro,350,0,0,293,1,26
  Pixel 6,350,81,21,216,100,228
  ```
- c.csv

  ```
  Device,Download,Transfer,Return,Processing,Wait,Overhead
  Pixel 6,350,0,0,436,2,43
  Pixel 3,350,140,46,187,52,206
  ```

[image: gnplot output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I tried to clean up and simplify your script. I included the data as datablocks, so it is simply copy & paste & run.
Check `help sum`, `help columnheader`... I hope the rest is self-explaining.

**Script:**

```
### rowstacked histogram with total above bars
reset session

$DataA <<EOD
Device,Download,Transfer,Return,Processing,Wait,Overhead
Find X2 Pro,350,0,0,287,1,24
OnePlus 8,350,29,19,410,30,138
EOD

$DataB <<EOD
Device,Download,Transfer,Return,Processing,Wait,Overhead
Find X2 Pro,350,0,0,293,1,26
Pixel 6,350,81,21,216,100,228
EOD

$DataC <<EOD
Device,Download,Transfer,Return,Processing,Wait,Overhead
Pixel 6,350,0,0,436,2,43
Pixel 3,350,140,46,187,52,206
EOD

set datafile separator ","
set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid
set style data histograms
set style histogram rowstack

set offset -1.3,-0.3,100,0
set xrange [0:]
set xtics font ", 10" right rotate by 45
set yrange [0:*]
set ylabel "Time (ms)"
set key outside right top noautotitle

mySum(n) = sum [_i=2:7] column(_i)

plot newhistogram at 2, \
         for [i=2:7] $DataA u i:xtic(1) ti columnheader(i) lc i-1, \
         '' u ($0+1):(total=mySum(0)):(sprintf('%d', total)) w labels offset 0,0.7, \
     newhistogram at 4,\
         for [i=2:7] $DataB u i:xtic(1) lc i-1, \
         '' u ($0+4):(total=mySum(0)):(sprintf('%d', total)) w labels offset 0,0.7, \
     newhistogram at 7, \
         for [i=2:7] $DataC u i:xtic(1) lc i-1, \
         '' u ($0+7):(total=mySum(0)):(sprintf('%d', total)) w labels offset 0,0.7, \
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]