# GNUPLOT - Can't display values over the bar

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I'm trying make simple histogram with this file '.dat'

```
Moment "Energy consumed (MWh)"
"Apr-16" 2011.4
"May-16" 1869.6
"Jun-16" 1899.0
"Jul-16" 1659.0
"Aug-16" 1740.6
"Sep-16" 1670.0
```

For this purpose I have written the following script

```
  #!/usr/bin/gnuplot
  set term postscript
  set terminal pngcairo nocrop enhanced size 700,700 font "arial,18"
  set termoption dash
  set output out
  set boxwidth 0.5 absolute
  set border 0
  set style fill   solid 1.00 border lt -1
  set key off
  set style histogram clustered gap 1 title textcolor lt -1
  set datafile missing '-'
  set style data histograms
  set xtics border in scale 0,0 nomirror autojustify
  set xtics  norangelimit
  set xtics ()
  unset ytics
  set title titulo
  set yrange [0.0000 : limite] noreverse nowriteback

  show style line
  set style line 1 lt 1 lc rgb color lw 1

  ## Last datafile plotted: "immigration.dat"
  plot fuente using (column(0)):2:xtic(1) title titulo ls 1 with boxes, '' using 0:2:2 with labels
```

In this case `out` is the output filename, `titulo` is the label that appears on the top of the image output, `limite` is the value that I use as biggest value on y-axi, and `fuente` is the source filename.

The result is this

[image]

I am trying display the values over the bar with some offset because I need the values over the bars and not inside the bars. I would need separate I am trying with code like:

```
plot fuente using (column(0)):2:xtic(1) title titulo ls 1 with boxes, '' using 0:($2 + 0.5):2 with labels
```

because I have seen many sites where they get it doing `$2 + 0.5` but this it doesn't work for me.

What should I do? Please help me I am completly lost. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `offset` parameter for the `with labels` plotting styles. With this you can add a vertical offset which you specify e.g. in `character` or `graph` units:

```
plot fuente using 0:2:xtic(1) with boxes, '' using 0:2:2 with labels offset 0, char 1
```

Sidenote: Adding the constant value of `0.5` to the y-value (like `$2 + 0.5`) doesn't work for you, because the `0.5` is in units of the y-axis, and very small compared to your yrange.

Comment: I spent hours and hours with that, thank you very much

Comment: I saw your gnuplot reputation, could yo help me with that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40484582/gnuplot-two-columns-histogram-with-values-on-top-of-bars @Christoph