# GNUPLOT - Two columns histogram with values on top of bars

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

yesteraday I made a similar question ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40469555/gnuplot-cant-display-values-over-the-bar)). I could not display the value on top of bar in a gnuplot histogram. I lost many time because I couldn't find really good documentation about it, and I only can find similar issues on differents websites.

I lost many time with that but fortunately someone give me the solution. Now I am having a similar issue with an histogram with two bars, in which I have to put on top of both bars its value. I am quite near, or that is what I think, but I can't make it work properly. I am changing the script and regenerating the graph many times but I am not sure of what I am doing.

**script.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
set term postscript
set terminal pngcairo nocrop enhanced size 600,400 font "Siemens Sans,8"
set termoption dash
set output salida
set boxwidth 0.8 absolute
set border 1
set style fill solid 1.00 border lt -1
set key off
set style histogram clustered gap 1 title textcolor lt -1
set datafile missing '-'
set style data histograms
set xtics border in scale 0,0 nomirror autojustify
set xtics  norangelimit
set xtics ()
unset ytics
set title titulo font 'Siemens Sans-Bold,20'
set yrange [0.0000 : limite1] noreverse nowriteback
set y2range [0.0000 : limite2] noreverse nowriteback
show style line


set style line 1 lt 1 lc rgb color1 lw 1
set style line 2 lt 1 lc rgb color2 lw 1

## Last datafile plotted: "immigration.dat"
plot fuente using 2:xtic(1) ls 1 ti col axis x1y1, '' u 3 ls 2 ti col axis x1y2, '' u 0:2:2 with labels offset -3,1 , '' u 0:2:3 with labels offset 3,1
```

I am modifying the last code line, because is here where I set the labels. I have been able to show both labels, but in bad positions, I have also been able to show one of the labels in the right position but no the other. I have been able to show almost everything but the thing that I want. This is the graph that generates the script.

**output.png**

[image]

This is the source file that I use for generating the graph

**source.dat**

```
"Momento" "Torre 1" "Torre 2" 
"May-16" 1500.8 787.8
"Jun-16" 1462.3 764.1
"Jul-16" 1311.2 615.4
"Ago-16" 1199.0 562.0
"Sep-16" 1480.0 713.8
"Oct-16" 1435.1 707.8
```

And that's the command that I execute with the parameters set

```
gnuplot -e "titulo='Energía consumida por torre (MWh)'; salida='output.png'; fuente='source.dat'; color1='#FF420E'; color2='#3465A4'; limite1='1800.96'; limite2='945.36'" script.sh
```

I think that is quite obvious what I am pretending, can someone help me?

Lots of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script has several problems, the missing `ti col` is only one of them. (You can also use `set key auto columnheader`, then you must not give that option every time).

- Don't use both `y1` and `y2` axis if you want to compare the values! Otherwise the correct bar heights are only a matter of luck...
- Understand, how gnuplot positions the histogram bars, then you can exactly locate the top center of each bar. If you only use `offset` with `char` values (which is the case when you give only numbers), then your script will break as soon as you add or remove a data row.

The histogram clusters start at x-position `0`, and are positioned centered at integer x values. Since you have two bars in each cluster and a gap of 1, the center of the first bar is at `($0 - 1/6.0)` (= `1/(2 * (numberOfTorres + gapCount))`), the second one at `($0 + 1/6.0)`:

```
set terminal pngcairo nocrop enhanced size 600,400 font ",8"
set output 'output.png'
set title 'Energía consumida por torre (MWh)' font ",20"
set boxwidth 0.8 absolute
set border 1
set style fill solid 1.00 border lt -1
set style histogram clustered gap 1 title textcolor lt -1
set style data histograms
set xtics border scale 1,0 nomirror autojustify norangelimit
unset ytics

set key off auto columnheader
set yrange [0:*]
set offset 0,0,graph 0.05,0

set linetype 1 lc rgb '#FF420E'
set linetype 2 lc rgb '#3465A4'
# dx = 1/(2 * (numberOfTorres + gap))
dx = 1/6.0

plot 'source.dat' using 2:xtic(1),\
     '' u 3,\
     '' u ($0 - dx):2:2 with labels,\
     '' u ($0 + dx):3:3 with labels
```

[image]

Now, starting at the bars center you can safely use `offset` to specify only the offset relative to the bars top center:

```
plot 'source.dat' using 2:xtic(1),\
         '' u 3,\
         '' u ($0 - dx):2:2 with labels offset -1,1 ,\
         '' u ($0 + dx):3:3 with labels offset 1,1
```

[image]

A second option would be to use the label's alignment: The labels of the red bars are right aligned at the bars right border, the labels of the blue bars are left aligned at the bars left border:

```
absoluteBoxwidth = 0.8
dx = 1/6.0 * (1 - absoluteBoxwidth)/2.0

plot 'source.dat' using 2:xtic(1),\
         '' u 3,\
         '' u ($0 - dx):2:2 with labels right offset 0,1 ,\
         '' u ($0 + dx):3:3 with labels left offset 0,1
```

[image]

In any case, both options make your script more robust against changes of the input data.

Comment: sorry man, but I would need you help again, could you check this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587961/gnuplot-assign-colours-in-pie-chart @Christoph

Answer (score 2):

This looks better :
[image]

```
plot fuente using 3:xtic(1) ls 1 ti col axis x1y1, '' u 3 ls 2 ti col axis x1y2, '' u ($0-1):3:3 with labels offset -3,1 , '' u ($0-1):2:2 with labels offset 3,1
```

You had 2 plots commands: only the first one was displayed.
Also, script.sh should be a bash script. This is a gnuplot script, so it should have another extension.

Comment: Thanks you very much! The guy I gave the correct answer is my workmate he find out what was happening and I invite him answer it here! In addition, the look of his graph is a little closest because there is less margin between labels and bars! Thanks you a lot anyway

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `ti col` tab. You need to put it in every option, including labels and not only in bars. The right code is:

```
plot fuente using 2:xtic(1) ls 1 ti col, '' u 3 ls 2 ti col, '' u 0:2:2 ti col with labels offset -3,1 , '' u 0:3:3 ti col with labels offset 3,1
```

And that's how the picture is displayed now:

[image]

You can also avoid `ti col` and that is how it would look:

[image]