# Multiplot of variable length data using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, subplot, variable-length-array

Here I have two data files with model parameters and RMSEs computed for them. I would like to get those RMSEs plotted for each model separately with the model also displayed on it.

Please help.

**Data file 1:**

```
20         ! # models
1 0.1      ! Theta inc.
3 4 7      ! Approximations
2          ! # layers
GK         ! model name
1.0 1.5    ! X-axis values (length varies for other models)
1.0 1.5    ! Y-axis values (length varies for other models)
2       
GK_MOD1 
1.0 1.5 
1.5 1.0 
4
Song
2.0 3.0 3.5 4.0
2.5 1.0 0.8 1.3
6
Causse
1.5  1.8  1.9  2.0  2.1  2.2
0.25 0.40 0.60 0.20 0.50 0.55
...
...
```

**Data file 2 (reformatted):**

```
#   TKfull   GKfull   Padefull_3   Padefull_7   TK1   Pade1_3   Pade1_7  Pade2_3   Pade2_7   GK1   Pade3_3   Pade3_7   GK2   PadeEnd_3 PadeEnd_7   GKEnd
GK                  0.071     0.028     0.025     0.156     0.023     0.004    0.045     0.012     0.232     0.013     0.090     0.492     0.064   0.064     0.384     0.046
GK_MOD1             0.055     0.030     0.053     0.156     0.012     0.008    0.036     0.050     0.185     0.025     0.169     0.497     0.107   0.125     0.375     0.075
GK_MOD2             0.132     0.042     0.081     0.209     0.035     0.006    0.050     0.051     0.277     0.036     0.267     0.625     0.116   0.192     0.484     0.079
GK_MOD3             0.261     0.067     0.316     0.267     0.066     0.021    0.078     0.138     0.426     0.063     1.137     0.855     0.161   0.810     0.662     0.106
Song                0.082     0.045     0.042     0.163     0.021     0.005    0.027     0.028     0.151     0.050     0.130     0.486     0.156   0.094     0.360     0.106
Song_MOD1           0.087     0.049     0.069     0.171     0.013     0.006    0.025     0.037     0.148     0.051     0.216     0.520     0.175   0.155     0.382     0.120
Song_MOD2           0.109     0.048     0.028     0.179     0.021     0.005    0.030     0.024     0.170     0.048     0.084     0.527     0.161   0.062     0.391     0.110
Song_MOD3           0.073     0.043     0.029     0.145     0.017     0.003    0.024     0.018     0.134     0.049     0.092     0.440     0.156   0.066     0.325     0.105
Cooper_basin        0.031     0.034     0.030     0.105     0.012     0.003    0.016     0.018     0.085     0.055     0.089     0.306   0.139     0.065     0.228     0.093
Cooper_basin_MOD1   0.035     0.017     0.024     0.093     0.016     0.006     0.031     0.034     0.151     0.042     0.083     0.297   0.076     0.063     0.236     0.047
Cooper_basin_MOD2   0.049     0.032     0.032     0.134     0.013     0.005     0.029     0.030     0.150     0.040     0.102     0.412   0.111     0.076     0.312     0.077
Causse2000_1        0.030     0.019     0.020     0.093     0.012     0.004     0.024     0.022     0.121     0.035     0.062     0.286   0.081     0.047     0.219     0.053
Causse2000_2        0.068     0.038     0.014     0.146     0.017     0.001     0.028     0.007     0.151     0.043     0.047     0.444   0.130     0.033     0.332     0.089
Causse2000_3        0.042     0.036     0.023     0.083     0.015     0.005     0.008     0.023     0.156     0.049     0.065     0.195   0.132 0.049     0.177     0.089
Causse2000_4        0.039     0.046     0.046     0.109     0.016     0.003     0.024     0.011     0.049     0.053     0.137     0.318   0.158     0.099     0.230     0.108
Dunkin_1973         0.653     0.641     0.656     0.686     0.703     0.703     0.725     0.239     0.471     0.059     0.434     0.632   0.140     0.353     0.557     0.093
Dunkin_1973_MOD1    0.708     0.624     0.708     0.709     0.694     0.692     0.692     0.760     0.761     0.042     0.785     0.792   0.104     0.773     0.777     0.070
Dunkin_1973_MOD2    0.043     0.029     0.026     0.118     0.050     0.004     0.025     0.023     0.130     0.039     0.082     0.357   0.105     0.061     0.270     0.072
Dunkin_1973_MOD3    0.012     0.014     0.005     0.066     0.011     0.001     0.022     0.002     0.102     0.032     0.017     0.210   0.070     0.012     0.165     0.046
Random              0.033     0.039     0.042     0.114     0.013     0.001     0.017     0.014     0.096     0.047     0.138     0.361   0.140   0.099     0.268     0.097
```

[image]
[Transposed the Data file 2 using this code](https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/f_src/file_transpose/file_transpose.html) then through the following script, plotted the RMSE values as shown in the image.

**Gnuplot script**

```
set terminal png size 800,500 enhanced font "Helvetica,20"
set output 'output.png'

red = "#FF0000"; green = "#00FF00"; blue = "#0000FF"; skyblue = 
"#87CEEB";
set yrange [0:2]
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 1
set style fill solid
set boxwidth 0.9
set xtics format ""
set grid ytics
set xtics rotate by 90 right
set title "A Sample Bar Chart"
plot "RMSE_transpose.dat" using 2:xtic(1) title "GK " linecolor rgb red
```

The inset figure in the image is *hand-drawn*, which is the model itself as shown in *Data file 1*.

*Help needed in:*

1. How to get such a plot from both the Data files for all the models,
   viz., GK, GK_MOD1, GK_MOD2, etc., with individual image having model
   name as the file name, such as, GK_RMSE.png,  GK_MOD1_RMSE.png, etc.
2. How to display the Y-axis values on top of each bar?
3. What should I modify in the Gnuplot script to get row-wise and
   column-wise plots from the Data file 2?

Comment: You should really ask a question. You did not ask any question (ignoring the "Can anyone please help!" which also does not have a questionmark, but as a question is off-topic). Did you encounter some problem using some simple attempt? What kind of problem? See [ask] and [mcve]. Also, text data examples should be copied and pasted as text, not as pictures. Some answerer may want to copy and paste the example data to their computer.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава My bad. Updated my question as you suggested. Please let me know should it be refined further. Thank you.

Comment: How should the data be plotted? What do the rows and the columns mean? What should gnuplot do with those numbers? You likely want the data in some different format.

Comment: @user86927 I'm confused as well. If it is difficult to describe in words, please add a freehand sketch about how the data should be used in the graph and how the graph should look like.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I reformatted the data file as you suggested. Help need for further tasks.

Comment: @user86927 thanks for your clarifications. How should the x and y values from file 1 be plotted? A step graph like you've shown? So, x always starts from 0? Can you show some example data with more that two x,y pairs? Are you maybe flexible with dataformat of file 1? The format is a bit unfortunate for gnuplot, which prefers x,y values in columns, not in rows.

Comment: @theozh Thank you for your response. I have added few more example data to the data file 1. Yes, the first row consists the X values and the second row the Y values, of each model (such as, GK, GK_MOD1, Song, Causse, etc).  The Y-values are the thicknesses of each layer. So, the values should be shown as-it-is but plotting location on Y-axis should be calculated from the first layer.
I agree that the data format in 'file 1' seems difficult but that is the feasible format for FORTRAN to read data of a model and do computations. Please let me know the feasibility of plotting?

Comment: @user86927 on StackOverflow, questions should be focused on one topic/aspect only. You have 3 questions. Btw, question 2: is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71207593 Difficulties makes the dataformat of file 1. It will be most likely a pain to plot this with gnuplot. Well, you could use an external tool to convert it into something which is more favorable for gnuplot (I typically prefer gnuplot-only solutions). Since data/labels of file1 and file2 are related, please add either minimized or full data, but a *complete* data example. Otherwise reasonable testing will be difficult.

Comment: @theozh Thank you so much for your time and the script. Unfortunately, I couldn't run it on my computer. I saved it with '.p' extension and used the syntax: `gnuplot bar_multiplot.p`

I receive an error message:

reset session
      ^
"bar_multiplot.p", line 3: warning: expected optional axis name

reset session
      ^
"bar_multiplot.p", line 3: ';' expected

Even if I comment that statement,  I receive another error message saying,

set datafile separator "\n"
                       ^
"bar_multiplot.p", line 10: extra chars after <separation_char>

Please help.

Comment: @user86927 which version of gnuplot are you running on which operating system? From the command line you should run it like `gnuplot -c bar_multiplot.p`

Comment: @theozh I am using 'gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 2' on CentOS through Oracle virtual box.
I tried running the script with '-c' and it says 
    unrecognized option -c

    set datafile separator "\n"
                       ^
    "bar_multiplot.p", line 10: extra chars after <separation_char>

Comment: @user86927 this might be the reason. That's why you should always mention your gnuplot version and system right from the beginning. Well, 4.6.2 is about 10 years old. Can't you update? If not, try to change the lines to `reset` (i.e. remove `session`) and `set datafile separator '|'` or any character which doesn't appear in your datafile. Well, I just see that more doesn't work for 4.6. Can't you update?

Comment: @theozh It says gnuplot is updated but shows only 4.6. After your suggestions and removing the word 'noenhanced' I get a gray scale image of just data file 2 for only the first model with the following information:

Comment: line 57: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points;
set output FileOut(rowLabel(row));
set multiplot;
set size 1,1;
set origin 0,0;
set xrange[*:*];
set yrange[0:*];
set offset 0.5,0.5,0,0;
set xtic rotate by 90 right ;
set title rowLabel(row) ;
plot for [i=1:words(colLabels)] FILE2 every ::row-1::row-1 u (i+1):colLabel(i):xtic(colLabel(i)) w boxes lc "red" notitle;;
set datafile separator "\n";
c=NaN;
stats FILE1 u (word(strcol(1),1) eq rowLabel(row) ? c=$0 : 0, c+1==$0 ? Xs=strcol(1) : c+2==$0 ? Ys=strcol(1) : 0 ) nooutput;
set datafile separator whitespace;

Comment: set xrange[word(Xs,1):word(Xs,words(Xs))];
set yrange[0:*] ;
set offset 0,0,0,0;
set xtic rotate by 0 center;
set samples words(Xs);
set size 0.4,0.4;
set origin 0.08,0.45;
unset title;
plot '+' u (i=int($0+1),x0=real(word(Xs,i))):(y0=real(word(Ys,i))) w histeps lc "blue" lw 2;
unset multiplot;
set size 1,1;
set origin 0,0^
line 57: extra chars after <separation_char>

Comment: @theozh It feels embarrassing that I couldn't figure out the error messages, as I am no expert in this. However, I get the following message after using the updated script.

cannot open file; output not changed
line 59: util.c: No such file or directory

I couldn't find where this 'util.c' is!?
Seems something flawed in my OS or gnuplot?

Comment: @user86927 This looks like some basic installation issue. Sorry, I can't help with Linux. But can you call a simple script file `test.gp` with the content `plot sin(x)` via `gnuplot -p -c test.gp` and it will be plotted?

Comment: @theozh: I tried the following with 'png' and 'pdf' too. Both worked.
`set term png
set output 'test.png'
plot sin(x)
set output`

gnuplot with and without `-p` worked but not `-c`. It says, 'unrecognized option -c'

Comment: @user86927 ok, it seems option `-c` is not available in 4.x and not really necessary. Well, but then I don't understand why the script in my answer does not run correctly and gnuplot complains about `util.c`. It seems something went wrong when building/installing your gnuplot. Try updating gnuplot to >=5.4

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
Below is now a version which works for gnuplot>=4.6.0 (March 2012).
It was a bit a struggle to get it to work for gnuplot 4.6.0, since gnuplot 4.x doesn't know `reset session` and `set datafile separator "\n"`, but for the rest which didn't work I can't exactly tell what it was. Something with the column header and the comment char, but seems now to be eliminated.

Here is a starting point for further optimization.

As mentioned in the comments, gnuplot doesn't like data in rows. So, plotting file1 in it's original format requires some extra lines.

A few comments:

- get the column labels and row labels into variables (`colLabels` and `rowLabels`)
- loop these strings/lists (check `help word`) for creating your graph by either columns or rows
- for plotting the x,y rows from file1 get the lines into strings `Xs` and `Ys`
- plot `Xs` versus `Ys` by using the special-file `'+'` (check `help special-filenames`).
- maybe the plotting style `with histeps` comes closest to what I understand you want to have from file1

I hope you can figure out the rest yourself by checking `help ...`.

There are a lot of ways to optimize the script, depending on your exact requirements and data which I don't know in detail.

You can answer your question 2 yourself as homework: see [How to display actual values on top of each bar in a bar-plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71207593/7295599)

**Data:**

`SO77228821_1.dat` (no text allowed after x,y values)

```
20         ! # models
1 0.1      ! Theta inc.
3 4 7      ! Approximations
2          ! # layers
GK         ! model name
1.0 1.5
1.0 1.5
2       
GK_MOD1 
1.0 1.5 
1.5 1.0 
4
Song
2.0 3.0 3.5 4.0
2.5 1.0 0.8 1.3
6
Causse2000_1
1.5  1.8  1.9  2.0  2.1  2.2
0.25 0.40 0.60 0.20 0.50 0.55
```

`SO77228821_2.dat`  (shortened from OP's file2 because OP's file1 was not complete)

```
#   TKfull   GKfull   Padefull_3   Padefull_7   TK1   Pade1_3   Pade1_7  Pade2_3   Pade2_7   GK1   Pade3_3   Pade3_7   GK2   PadeEnd_3 PadeEnd_7   GKEnd
GK                  0.071     0.028     0.025     0.156     0.023     0.004    0.045     0.012     0.232     0.013     0.090     0.492     0.064   0.064     0.384     0.046
GK_MOD1             0.055     0.030     0.053     0.156     0.012     0.008    0.036     0.050     0.185     0.025     0.169     0.497     0.107   0.125     0.375     0.075
Song                0.082     0.045     0.042     0.163     0.021     0.005    0.027     0.028     0.151     0.050     0.130     0.486     0.156   0.094     0.360     0.106
Causse2000_1        0.030     0.019     0.020     0.093     0.012     0.004     0.024     0.022     0.121     0.035     0.062     0.286   0.081     0.047     0.219     0.053
```

**Script:** (tested with gnuplot 4.6.0 and 5.4.5)

```
### create graphs from row/column headers 
### and graph inset from second file with row-wise data
reset
unset multiplot

FILE1 = "SO/SO77228821_1.dat"
FILE2 = "SO/SO77228821_2.dat"

# get all row-labels and column-labels
set datafile commentschar ''
set datafile separator "|"
rowLabels = ''
stats FILE2 u ($0==0? colLabels=strcol(1) : rowLabels=rowLabels.' '.word(strcol(1),1)) nooutput
set datafile separator whitespace

rowLabel(i) = word(rowLabels,i)
colLabel(i) = word(colLabels,i)
FileOut(s)  = sprintf("SO/SO77228821_%s_RMSE.png",s)

set boxwidth 0.7
set style fill solid 0.3
set key noautotitle

set term pngcairo size 640,384 font ",10" noenhanced

# create graphs by rowLabel
do for [row=1:words(rowLabels)] {
    set output FileOut(rowLabel(row))
    set multiplot
        set size 1,1
        set origin 0,0
        set bmargin 4.5
        set xrange[*:*]
        set yrange[0:*]
        set offset 0.5,0.5,0,0
        set xtic rotate by 90 right
        set title rowLabel(row)
        plot for [i=2:words(colLabels)] FILE2 every ::row::row u (i+1):i:xtic(colLabel(i)) w boxes lc rgb "red" notitle

        set datafile separator "|"
        c=NaN
        stats FILE1 u (word(strcol(1),1) eq rowLabel(row) ? c=$0 : 0, c+1==$0 ? Xs=strcol(1) : c+2==$0 ? Ys=strcol(1) : 0 ) nooutput
        set datafile separator whitespace
        set xrange[word(Xs,1):word(Xs,words(Xs))]
        set yrange[0:*] 
        set offset 0,0,0,0
        set xtic rotate by 0 center
        set size 0.4,0.4
        set origin 0.08,0.45
        set bmargin -1
        unset title
        set samples words(Xs)
        plot '+' u (i=int($0+1),x0=real(word(Xs,i))):(y0=real(word(Ys,i))) w histeps lc rgb "blue" lw 2
    unset multiplot
    set size 1,1
    set origin 0,0
    set output
}

# create graphs by colLabel
do for [col=2:words(colLabels)] {
    set output FileOut(colLabel(col))
    set title colLabel(col)
    set datafile commentschar    # reset to default
    set xrange[*:*]
    set yrange[0:*]
    plot FILE2 u 0:col:xtic(1) w boxes lc rgb "web-green" notitle
}
set output
### end of script
```

**Result:** (just two examples out of the many files generated)

[image]

[image]