# Incorrect position and size of percentages in Gnu Plot

Tags: linux, bash, gnuplot, cgi

I have developped a CGI in bash/html that allow me to generate a graph of my clusters.

Here is an exemple : 
[image]

This is a graph that works well.  The problem is that for some graphs, the percentages overlap or shift far too far from where it should be. Here is my GNUPLOT code:

```
f(w) = (strlen(w) > 10 ? word(w, 1) . "\n" . word(w, 2) : w)

set title "TITLE"
set terminal png truecolor size 960, 720 background rgb "#eff1f0"
set output "/var/www/html/CLUSTER_NAME.png"
set bmargin at screen 0.1
set key top center
set grid
set style data histograms
set style fill solid 1.00 border -1
set boxwidth 0.7 relative
set yrange [*:*]
set format y "%g%%"
set datafile separator ","
plot 'test1.txt' using 2:xtic(f(stringcolumn(1))) title " CPU consumption (%) ", \
'' using 3 title " RAM consumption (%)", \
'' using 0:($2+1):(sprintf(" %g%%",$2)) with labels notitle, \
'' using 0:($3+1):(sprintf("     %g%%",$3)) with labels notitle
```

Here is an example of a graph that does not work properly because the percentages are too shifted :

[image]

I am able to change this by changing this line in my code:

```
'' using 0:($3+1):(sprintf(" %g%%",$3)) with labels notitle
```

To :

```
'' using 0:($3+1):(sprintf("                               %g%%",$3)) with labels notitle
```

Adding spaces allows to shift the percentages :

[image]

But even if it works for this graph, it moves the percentages for the other graphs too... :

[image]

I can't get "clean" graphics. Either the percentages overlap, or they go out of scope because the values are too large, or they are completely shifted....

Another example:
[image]

Is there a way to make all this move by itself, automatically, according to the values and therefore the size of the bars etc?

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE)

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Adding code and pictures for something working as expected is not helpful and wastes time and space.

Comment: See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40492423/2604213, about how histograms are built. The key is get the top center of the box with `using` and shift from there with `offset`: `plot ... using ... with labels offset ...`

Answer (score 0):

You might try an alternative mechanism, using `plot for [i=2:3] ...` to loop through the 2 columns of values. Instead of guessing the number of spaces to indent, you estimate the x position of the bar using `column(0)+(i-2)*.25` (for i = 2 then 3), 
which I got to by trial and error.

For example, using a function `mytitle` to get the 2 titles (my gnuplot is too old for an array):

```
mytitle(x) = (x==2?"cpu":"ram")
plot for [i=2:3] 'data' using i:xtic(stringcolumn(1)) title mytitle(i), \
     for [i=2:3] '' using (column(0)+(i-2)*.25):(column(i)+1):\
      (sprintf("%g%%",column(i))) with labels notitle
```

[image: plots]